# An example of arrays being used in web development

Tags: php, arrays

I was talking to a person today who mentioned he used arrays when calling parameters or for other reasons when pulling data from the database etc.

Basically my question is: how would you use arrays in web development?

For example:

If you had a url like this (a social dating site)

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?sid=1&agefrom=30&ageto=40&sex=female&loccation=los angeles
```

How I would query the browse page (when showing a list of users) is

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$agefrom = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['agefrom']);
$ageto = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ageto']);
$sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sex']);
$location = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['location']);

mysql_query("select from table where id = '$id' and  agefrom='$agefrom' [.....the rest of the query]")
```

Can this be done with arrays? What if a location wasn't selected or the age wasn't entered? If i did the query it might fail.

I hope my question is more clear now.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how you can substitute arrays for if statements, which is an odd request. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays make it easy to hold a set of values, or key => value pairs, inside a variable.  It also makes it easy to iterate over a set of values.

```
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value)
{
  // do something with this key and value
}
```

If you are passing a large number of values to a function, and this set of values could be thought of as a list or a lookup table, then you would use an array.

Please [consult the PHP manual on arrays](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for more information.

**Edit:**

I think I see what you mean now.  It can be helpful to sort of 'abstract' your database calls by creating a function that accepts values as an array.  For example:

```
function editrecord($recordid, $values)
{
  // SQL is generated by what is in $values, and then query is run
  // remember to check keys for validity and escape values properly      
}
```

That's an extreme simplication of course.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are an important feature of any language, they have O(1) ([constant time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_time)) random access and can be used as a base data structure to make more complex types.

Specifically talking [about PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), the arrays are used VERY often, the language itself uses them for example to grab the [GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) parameters.

To get data, you can also make use of arrays in PHP.

You can use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), this will retch a result row from the database as an associative array, each index of the array will represent a column of data of the current row:

```
//...
$sql = "SELECT id as userid, fullname, userstatus 
        FROM   sometable
        WHERE  userstatus = 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Here, the $row variable is an associative array.
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```